# WixSilentExec does not work

Tags: wix, custom-action

I've got to silently run some cmd line on uninstall. I'm trying to use WixSilentExec but it does not work. What is the problem ?

```
    <Property Id="WixSilentExecCmdLine" Value='cmd /C "rmdir /s/q [DataBaseDir]"' Hidden="yes"/>
    <CustomAction Id="RemoveDataDir" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixSilentExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RemoveDataDir" Before="RemoveFiles">DELETEDATADIR="1" OR FORCEDELETE="1") AND (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Directory Id="DataBaseDir" Name="$(var.DataBaseDirName)">
          <Component Id="DataBaseDir.dir" Guid="*">
               <CreateFolder/>
          </Component>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Did you try running custom action without condition, to detect, if problem is in action call, or its condition? You are missing `(` at the start of condition `DELETEDATADIR="1" OR FORCEDELETE="1")` => `(DELETEDATADIR="1" OR FORCEDELETE="1")`

Comment: Shared own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The name `cmd` can not be resolved and quoted executable name  should be used instead :`"cmd.exe"`
2. SetProperty should be used as the installer can not resolve `[DataBaseDir]`
3. Sequence `execute` should be set

   ```
   <Property Id="RemoveDataDir" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>
   <SetProperty Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Before="RemoveDataDir" Sequence="execute" Value='"cmd.exe" /c rmdir /s/q "[DataBaseDir]"'>1</SetProperty>
   ```